# Retrieve spotlight search text from ios device

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, corespotlight, nsuseractivity

I am working on core spotlight feature of ios 9. 
    When type any search text on spotlight search, app contents display in below list and we can navigate to respective application when tap on it.

Below delegate is call when tap on content.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:( NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler
 { 
 }
```

I need search text which type on spotlight search.

Example - Suppose I type 'Music' in spotlight search ,musical app list display in below list.On tap on it,navigates to musical app .

How do I retrieve 'Music' in my application ?
 Please reply if any one has idea about it.

Comment: You can't get the search text, only what they tapped on

Comment: May i know why I cant get search text .I have search in core spotlight document but didnt get it

Comment: You can't get it because it just isn't a thing that apple makes available to you.  If you want to know why they don't make it available you'd have to ask them.

Comment: ok. thanks for you answer.